# Why is Internet Explorer not able to download a file?

Tags: internet-explorer

When I am trying to download a file in Internet Explorer, I am getting the below error message:

> Internet Explorer cannot download XXXXX from yyyy.com
>
> Internet Explorer was not able to open this Internet site. The requested site is either unavailable or cannot found. Please try agaian later.

But the same download works in Mozilla Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Check `Control Panel -> Internet Options` for proxies, other settings.
The problem should be there..somewhere.